# Unobserved task exception handling with TopShelf

Tags: c#, task, topshelf

I am using TopShelf framework which is just working great.
However I am having great trouble figuring out how to register a top level exception filter for unobserved task exceptions (i.e subscribing to TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException).

I tried different places to register to this event, but no matter what, I never get the notification when I throw exceptions from non awaited tasks.

How can I correctly get these notifications when using TopShelf.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad,

It had nothing related to TopShelf but to the behavior of TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException which must wait for the exception throwing task to be garbage collected before getting the exception :(